# I am having the error: module 'numpy' has no attribute 'dtype'

Tags: python

I am trying to import this module:
`from iexfinance.stocks import Stock`

It comes with the error 'numpy' has no attribute 'dtype'.
[full traceback here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z6EQr.png)
Modules are all up to date, and I am not sure what is going wrong. Tried reinstalling the modules as well.

Thanks!

Additionally, I have another problem that is annoying. For some reason pip installs modules to a folder inside of python, but then python doesnt recognise the modules unless they are in this other folder that I have created. It would be great if I could change where python looks for modules because every time I install a module I have to copy it over to the folder I have made, and then uninstalling things is even worse.

I tried reinstalling and updating all modules. Did not work.

Comment: Please edit the question and post the entire error message traceback.

Comment: share your traceback and the relevant part of your code.

Comment: _For some reason pip installs modules to a folder inside of python, but then python doesnt recognise the modules unless they are in this other folder that I have created_ It sounds a lot like you're using different versions of pip and python that don't know about each other.

Comment: Don't make us retype code from an image.  Please post everything as plain text.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. As per the first comment, please [include all the details in your post](/help/how-to-ask), including whether it's a _real_ error (i.e. generated by running your code) or an IDE hint (and then please mention which IDE you're using), and information on which version of python/pip you're using, and don't use pictures of text: show that text, as text (wich [code mardown](/markdown) as needed) in your post.

Comment: it is a real error

Comment: he means that instead of posting your error as an image, you should post it as marked down text. Read the links for @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans and fix the question